# HTTP GET request to API - localhost vs server. The request gets "duplicated/transformed" on the server

Tags: angularjs, http, get, slim

I am using Angular (front) and Slim (back).

When I make the request locally, it works fine and it returns the JSON.

```
http://localhost/domain/api/jobs
```

But when I make the same request on my server:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/jobs
```

I get a 404. Upon inspection, I'm seeing that the request sent is actually transformed into:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/~username/domain/api/jobs
```

I am unable to make the request as it keeps getting changed automatically. Why does this happen?

Here is the code:

Angular **app/service.factory.js**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .factory('jobService', jobService);

function jobService($http) {

    var baseUrl = 'api/';

    return {
        getJobs: getJobs,
    };

    function getJobs() {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + 'jobs');
    }
};
```

Angular **app/jobs.config.js**

```
angular
    .module('app')
    .config(config);

function config($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        templateUrl: 'templates/jobs-view.html',
        controller: JobController,
        controllerAs: 'jobCtrl'
    });
};

function JobController(jobService) {
    var that = this;

    jobService.getJobs().success(function (data) {
        that.jobs = data;
    });
};
```

Slim PHP **api/index.php**

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new \Slim\App; 

$app->get('/jobs', 'getJobs');

$app->run();

function getJobs() {
    $sql = "select * FROM jobs ORDER BY id";
    try {
        $db = getConnection();
        $stmt = $db->query($sql);  
        $jobs = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
        $db = null;
        echo json_encode($jobs);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
        echo '{"error":{"text":'. $e->getMessage() .'}}'; 
    }
}
```

Comment: You have something like $http.get('http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/jobs') and that is transformed to http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/~username/domain/api/jobs?

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe I have this `$http.get('api/jobs');`

Comment: May be define a constant, app.constant('BASE_API_URL', 'http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/') and inject it to where you are making api calls. Like app.service('jobService', function (BASE_API_URL) {}); Then, $http.get(BASE_API_URL + 'jobs') to make a request to jobs api?

Comment: @Ivan - Somewhere you have to be setting a base URL for your $http requests, right?  It almost seems like your Slim routing needs to be looked at, it is interpreting 'api/jobs' and setting it relative to a different base URL when on your server vs. local.  I don't know Slim otherwise I might have a more specific point.

Comment: I cannot think of any reason for transformation of the URL. If only i could debug the app itself.

Comment: I think Prashant's comment about injecting the URL is what you should do.  This is how I setup my Angular calls to any API... I don't use relative pathing.  There's just too much you're assuming when doing that.

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe I added the code if you want to have a  look at it. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @Marcidius I added the code if you want to have a look at it. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe When I try calling the API directly in the browser by pasting `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/jobs`, technically bypassing the Angular routing, I should be getting the JSON... But it gets duplicated regardless, resulting in a 404.

Comment: Check the networks tab in the developer tool of your brower. See if your server sends a redirect to the wrong url before sending a 404. If yes, your backend routing has the issue.

Comment: @PrashantPalikhe I tried something and I am really confused. I added the application under a domain and it works. Ex. `domain.com/api/jobs` works, whereas `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/jobs` doesn't... What gives? I contacted tech support and the guy told me that it was because of the PHP version... WTF?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you must try to use the full url instead of a relative path. I think that will solve the problem. so use http://domain.com/restful/api/commands instead of restful/api/commands .

Comment: Ok, but when I try calling the API directly in the browser by pasting `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/jobs`, technically bypassing the Angular routing, I should be getting the JSON... But it gets duplicated regardless, resulting in a 404.

Answer (score 1):

What if you try this in your api/index.php in place of the current $app->get:

$app->get('/~username/domain/api/jobs', 'getJobs');

Try that and see what the result is, curious if that might be part of it.  The talk about using the full URL vs the relative, at least in the context I'm referring to, is from the API perspective.

Comment: I tried something and I am really confused. I added the application under a domain and it works. Ex. `domain.com/api/jobs` works, whereas `http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/~username/domain/api/jobs` doesn't... What gives? I contacted tech support and the guy told me that it was because of the PHP version... WTF?

Comment: Did he say WHY though?  What your version of PHP is doing vs. what the latest versions do?  I'm still convinced it's how that version interprets the relative paths.  Did you try the above line change at all, did it give any different result?  Are you able to use the domain solution that you said is working as an ultimate fix?  In this case the domain is bypassing the pathing done by PHP by taking you directly to the location + '/api/jobs'.  Without the domain it is telling you the implied path of '/api/jobs' which so far has been incorrect.

Comment: Hey, I tried your suggestion. It doesn't work. NOTHING seems to work aside from using a domain vs IP/~username/... I really don't want to research this to no end, so I'm just sticking with using a domain. :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure thing, I'm glad you got it to work using the domain at least.  Good luck to you!

Comment: When I need to use /~username/ I always uses a subdomain. So for development things I have a domain and only uses the subdomains for that. It never felt good for me to use /~username/ for testing a website.

Comment: @DaniëlvanRijn Yeah, I'll be doing the same thing from now on.